# GitLab. Commit Pending

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been waiting for some time for the commit to end pending...

Foreword: I don't know how Continuous Integration works, but I don't need it...

How Can I solve this issue? I can't understand why the commit is pending.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitLab CI uses so-called `Runners` (a program on a computer) to build your commits after you pushed them. Those have to be available or otherwise your build will be pending until one becomes available.

You can setup a project specific runner in the project settings or one available to all projects in the Admin Area. Read the [GitLab CI quick start guide](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/) for more information.